# How to derive from a Qt MainWindow class?

Tags: qt, derived-class, qmainwindow

I have a Qt 4 base class that creates the main application dialog:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget *central = new QWidget;
    ...
    setCentralWidget(central);
}
```

I must not touch this code, but I can extend it with a derived class:

```
class MyWindow : public MainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

MyWindow::MyWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    MainWindow(parent);
    QWidget *myWidget = new QWidget;
    //???
}
```

I would like to add more widgets to the base class' central widget. How can I do it once `setCentralWidget()` has already been called in the base class?

Comment: When I copy this example, I get declaration of parent MainWindow(parent) shadows a parameter pointing at parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get access to central widget, using [QMainWindow::centralWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget) and add widgets or layouts to its layout, knowing its structure. A simple example:

```
QMainWindow::centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(new QLabel(tr("New label")));
```